# "Флюра" или "флюро"?

Tags: грамматика

Разрешите спор. Есть слово "флюорография". Многие говорят сокращённо, но как правильно: "флюра" или "флюро"? И склоняется ли это сокращение?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

На разговорные сокращения, не включенные в словари, нет правил. Как больше нравится, так и пишите.

Все рекомендации, не имеющие базы в виде авторитетных источников, можно смело признавать неаргументированными.

Comment: И я бы ещё добавила, что написание начальной формы зависит от того, как человек планирует его склонять. Если **во множественном числе номинатива** будет **флюрЫ**, то правильнее будет писать **флюрА** (это впишется в типы склонения по Зализняку), а если будет **флюрО** или **флюрА**, то писать в начальной форме **флюрО**.

Comment: @KseniaK да шут его знает... Понятно, что флюра склоняется, а флюро - не обязательно. Но можно ли делать это правилом, давая рекомендации по грамматике ненормативных образований? Т. е. там, где по определению нет и не может быть никаких правил... Схоластикой отдает.

Comment: Даже не знаю, где так говорят: из неформального слышал только "флюшка". Флюро(-) обычно относят к живописи флюоресцентными красками. Фиксируемое сокращение для флюорографии - аббревиатура ФГ.

Comment: @Alex_ander я тоже не могу уверенно сказать, что слышал такое. Но какое это имеет значение? Поверим автору. А все, мной сказанное, никак не опровергается отсутствием реальной фиксацией такого употребления. Только подтверждается, что говорить-то особо и не о чем.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ исправлен

**ФЛЮОРОГРАФИЯ,** -и; ж. [от лат. fluor - течение, поток и греч. gráphō - пишу]  Спец. Метод рентгенологического исследования, заключающийся в фотографировании изображения органов человеческого тела с просвечивающего экрана на фотоплёнку.

**Из толкового словаря русского школьного и студенческого жаргона (2005):**

**ФЛЮРА** (шк., студ.) Флюорография. На флюру два урока снимают (запись 2003 г.).

Слово не относится к нормативной лексике, поэтому **некорректно говорить о правильности или неправильности таких слов.** Склоняемая форма "флюра" более логична, так как сохраняет ж. р. существительного, именно она чаще применяется в молодежном жаргоне.

Comment: *Сокращенное произношение "флюра" или "флюро" не допускается, так как является отклонением от нормы. Произносятся все гласные, но безударные О при этом редуцируются, предударный гласный О произносится как звук, похожий на А.* - а где та норма прописана, и, коли вариант ненормативен, то какие могут быть рекомендации по его произношению?

Comment: В орфоэпических словарях упоминается это слово, но с другими проблемами: (1) перенос ударения "флюорографИя" (проф. или устар.) и  (2) произношение "флуорография", которое также не закрепилось в языке. Из этого следует, что в остальном  для этого слова действуют обычные произносительные нормы, то есть отсутствует пропуск гласных, но имеет место обычная редукция гласных в доударных и послеударных слогах.

Comment: Какое-такое "это слово"? Против слова "флюорография" и обсуждения его проблем я ничего не имею. А вот слова "флюро" как словарями не фиксируемое, лучше не обсуждать в таком ключе.

Comment: Да, я. пожалуй, не совсем поняла смысл заданного вопроса, так как никогда не слышала таких сокращений.  Но если уж сокращать, то лучше "флюра" (сохраняется ж.р.), тогда слово будет иметь 1-е склонение. Это ненормированная лексика, но при записи разговорной речи может использоваться.